# C# Select Nodes not finding nodes

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here but I've wrestled with it for a few days.  I'm hoping someone can point out what I am missing.

I receive a XML message from an outside source in the following simplified format:

```
<root>
  <A>
    <B xmlns="http://www.something.com/Document>
      <C>Value1</C> 
      <D>Value2</D>
      <E>Value3</E>
    </B>
  </A>
  <A>
    <B xmlns="http://www.something.com/Document>
      <D>Value5</D>
      <E>Value6</E>
    </B>
  </A>
</root>
```

I'm trying to pull out the D elements.

I've tried:

```
XmlNodeList xmlResults = xdPayload.SelectNodes("//D")
```

This returned no results. Then thinking that the namespace was the issue I tried:

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xdPayload.NameTable);
xnlResults = xdPayload.SelectNodes("//D", nsmgr);
```

Again no results.  I didn't think I needed to add in the default namespace but when thinking smart doesn't work think stupid.  So I tried this:

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xdPayload.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("", "http://www.something.com/Document");
xnlResults = xdPayload.SelectNodes("//D", nsmgr);
```

Still no results. I've tried more descriptive XPaths like "/root/A/B/D" and "/root/A/B[@xmlns="http://www.somewhere.com/Document"]/D" as well with no results as well.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: are you able to get the c node easily? how do you feel about getting the c node, then doing a .next() command?

Comment: I wouldn't mind going that route except 1) I cannot get C either and 2) C may or may not be there with every transmission. I probably should removed it from the second container for clarity.   Sorry about that

Comment: I don't know if this answer I once got would lead you down the correct path https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17068826/reading-an-xml-file-with-xdoc

Comment: or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961805/xpath-and-selectnodes-method  make sure your `AddNamespace is correct and not random ... what it would be ... idk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a prefix-named namespace and then refer to the `<D>` as `ns0:D`:

```
NameTable nt = new NameTable();
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(nt);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns0", "http://www.something.com/Document");
xnlResults = xdPayload.SelectNodes("/root/A/ns0:B/ns0:D", nsmgr);
```

This should select you the `<D>` elements for further processing.

---

If that doesn't work, you'll always have the option of ignoring all namespaces like with

```
XmlNodeList xmlResults = xdPayload.SelectNodes("//*[local-name()='D']")
```

Comment: The second option worked.  I would have liked to been a bit more surgical about how I pulled these but for this particular application, it shouldn't cause any issues.  Thanks for the assist!!

Answer (score 2):

Using [XElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement):

```
string text = @"
    <root>
        <A>
        <B xmlns='http://www.something.com/Document'>
            <C>Value1</C> 
            <D>Value2</D>
            <E>Value3</E>
        </B>
        </A>
        <A>
        <B xmlns='http://www.something.com/Document'>
            <D>Value5</D>
            <E>Value6</E>
        </B>
        </A>
    </root>";

XNamespace ns = "http://www.something.com/Document";
var xml = XElement.Parse(text);
var ds = xml.Descendants(ns + "D");
ds.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with the same issue. The key is the `Descendants()` method. Because you have `<root>` element, you have dig one level before you can start referring to the `<A>` and `<B>` elements.